# How to create array from data json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

I have JSON with dynamic data.

How I can create array address from data returned by JSON?

```
 var json= JSON.parse(result);

 var address = json.address;

 console.log(address) :

 2.26095199584961,2.2635269165039067,2.2908210754394536,2.2951126098632817
```

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is some JavaScript you're talking about, you might consider using:

`var yourVar = yourString.split(separator, limit)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, use split function to do the same

```
let addressArra = address.split(',');
```